# getting data-id attribute returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this might be similar question to others but i just cant fixed this so i have data-commentid attribute and it has a value from my database.

```
<div class="comment" data-commentid="24">
  <a href="#" class="pull-left">
    <!-- //Notice .comment-avatar class-->
    <img src="../assets/img/avatars/d-30x30.png" alt="D" class="comment-avatar">
  </a>
  <!-- //Notice .comment-body class-->
  <div class="comment-body">
    <!-- //Notice .message class-->
    <span class="message"><strong>Tobei Tsumura</strong> Really Nice</span>
    <!-- //Notice .time class-->
    <span class="time" data-livestamp=""></span>
    <!-- //Notice .like class-->
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" id="user_likes" class="like">Like&nbsp;</a>

    <span class="like" id="name"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="comment" data-commentid="25">
  <a href="#" class="pull-left">
    <!-- //Notice .comment-avatar class-->
    <img src="../assets/img/avatars/d-30x30.png" alt="D" class="comment-avatar">
  </a>
  <!-- //Notice .comment-body class-->
  <div class="comment-body">
    <!-- //Notice .message class-->
    <span class="message"><strong>Tobei Tsumura</strong> Really Nice</span>
    <!-- //Notice .time class-->
    <span class="time" data-livestamp=""></span>
    <!-- //Notice .like class-->
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" id="user_likes" class="like">Like&nbsp;</a>

    <span class="like" id="name"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment" data-commentid="26">
  <a href="#" class="pull-left">
    <!-- //Notice .comment-avatar class-->
    <img src="../assets/img/avatars/d-30x30.png" alt="D" class="comment-avatar">
  </a>
  <!-- //Notice .comment-body class-->
  <div class="comment-body">
    <!-- //Notice .message class-->
    <span class="message"><strong>Tobei Tsumura</strong> Really Nice</span>
    <!-- //Notice .time class-->
    <span class="time" data-livestamp=""></span>
    <!-- //Notice .like class-->
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" id="user_likes" class="like">Like&nbsp;</a>

    <span class="like" id="name"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

now using jquery i want to get the value from data-commentid

```
comid = $(this).find('.comment').attr('data-commentid');
```

data-commentid is rendered after a success of my ajax request...
i already tried diff approach just to get the value from data-commentid but it always returned undefined 
but when i try to `console.log(comid);` it returns undefined.

```
    var $htmlObjectComment = $($.parseHTML($.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'../htmlstrings/comment.html',
        cache:false,
        async:false
    }).responseText));

    $htmlObjectComment.attr('data-commentid', results);
    $htmlObjectComment.find('a img').attr({'src': $el_user.find('a img').attr('src'), 'width': 30, 'height': 30});
    $htmlObjectComment.find('div.comment-body').children('span.message').html('<strong>' + $('div.user span').html() + '</strong> ' + $form.find('input').val());
    $htmlObjectComment.find('div.comment-body').children('span.time').attr('data-livestamp', currentDateTime);

    $el.find('div.comment:last').before($htmlObjectComment);
    $form.find('input').val(null);
```

this is my ajax success request. and the comment.html is the html above..

this is what the `console.log($(this));` return..
[image]

Comment: Try logging your `$(this)` and see if it contains the right data.

Comment: i get this return [window]..

Comment: Just before `comid = $(this).find('.comment').attr('data-commentid');` write `console.log($(this))` and check if it contains your html page.

Comment: i can see the data-commentid was written on the innerHTML something like that..

Comment: Change `console.log($(this))` to `console.log($(this).find('.comment'))` and check the result if it contains the correct node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148992/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-lion-smith).

Comment: i change it to console.log($(this).find('.comment')) but i get the same result from b4 when i use console.log($(this)) the only difference is that instead of [window] on the first line it becomes r.fn.init(0)

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be with this line of code:

```
comid = $(this).find('.comment').attr('data-commentid');
```

Actually, `$(this).find('.comment')` returns an array not just a single object.
Please try changing your code to as given below:

```
        var comments = $(this).find('.comment');
        $.each(comments , function(index, item){
             var comid = $(item).attr('data-commentid');
             console.log(comid); 
             /*If it prints correct values, you can make necessary changes in this piece of code as per your needs*/
        });
```

Comment: i tried using the code below and putting it on `$(document).ready(function)` but nothing is being returned on the `console.log()`

Comment: `var comments = $('.comment');
        $.each(comments , function(index, item){
             var comid = $(item).data('commentid');
             console.log(comid); 
        })`
 A small tweak. Depending on how you decide to go, you could redefine "comments"

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.data()` like this:

`$(this).data('id')` and this will look for `data-id` on whatever `$(this)` refers to.

here's the api documentation link - http://api.jquery.com/data/

so for you, you can do: `$(this).find('.comment').data('commentid')` and if that doesn't work, console.log `$(this)` and then console.log `$(this).find('.comment')` - they might be outputting something different to what you want

### update

also as mentioned in another answer, `.comment` could be an array, as it is a class name rather than an id. Using `$.each` with `$(this).data('commentid')` should work :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try using 'prop' instead of 'attr'.

You can try this:

```
$(this).find('.comment').prop('data-commentid');
```

Comment: still returns undefined...basically the code i posted above was like liking a comment like on facebook.. i already have the like and unlike function for it but the main problem was the displaying part. cause i need to get the data-commentid so that it will display on the right commentid

Comment: no.. i use i frame for displaying video.but displaying comment i use div.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.comment').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-commentid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment" data-commentid="24">
  <a href="#" class="pull-left">
    <!-- //Notice .comment-avatar class-->
    <img src="../assets/img/avatars/d-30x30.png" alt="D" class="comment-avatar">
  </a>
  <!-- //Notice .comment-body class-->
  <div class="comment-body">
    <!-- //Notice .message class-->
    <span class="message"><strong>Tobei Tsumura</strong> Really Nice</span>
    <!-- //Notice .time class-->
    <span class="time" data-livestamp=""></span>
    <!-- //Notice .like class-->
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" id="user_likes" class="like">Like&nbsp;</a>

    <span class="like" id="name"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="comment" data-commentid="25">
  <a href="#" class="pull-left">
    <!-- //Notice .comment-avatar class-->
    <img src="../assets/img/avatars/d-30x30.png" alt="D" class="comment-avatar">
  </a>
  <!-- //Notice .comment-body class-->
  <div class="comment-body">
    <!-- //Notice .message class-->
    <span class="message"><strong>Tobei Tsumura</strong> Really Nice</span>
    <!-- //Notice .time class-->
    <span class="time" data-livestamp=""></span>
    <!-- //Notice .like class-->
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" id="user_likes" class="like">Like&nbsp;</a>

    <span class="like" id="name"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comment" data-commentid="26">
  <a href="#" class="pull-left">
    <!-- //Notice .comment-avatar class-->
    <img src="../assets/img/avatars/d-30x30.png" alt="D" class="comment-avatar">
  </a>
  <!-- //Notice .comment-body class-->
  <div class="comment-body">
    <!-- //Notice .message class-->
    <span class="message"><strong>Tobei Tsumura</strong> Really Nice</span>
    <!-- //Notice .time class-->
    <span class="time" data-livestamp=""></span>
    <!-- //Notice .like class-->
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;" id="user_likes" class="like">Like&nbsp;</a>

    <span class="like" id="name"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its kinda wierd but nothing console.log() doesn't return anyting. like it wasn't even called in the first place even if i put it inside $(document).ready(function)

Comment: Then, first find out solution to that and then try the solution provided here.